# Process maker - Login using rest api not working

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, api, session

Using the below script i am able to retrieve the cases related to a particular user using process makers rest api, but unable to go the home page and use the system as is (Somthing like a single sign on) after doing this, what am i missing here? I am redirecting to the page i want and its taking me to the login screen again. i am using app.js to call the rest api and index.php to display and enter login credentials. I am following this tutorial http://www.processmaker.com/tutorial-rest-api-angularjs, Please help

My app.js is as below:

```html
(function () {
  
  var app;
  app = angular.module('caseLister',[]);
  
  app.controller('listController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope){
    
    this.server_url = 'http://localhost';
    this.workspace = 'workflow';
    this.credentials = {
         grant_type   : 'password',
         scope        : '*',
         client_id    : 'GFFBDLKMOFFGRLQXELEOIBUVWQXUYANB',
         client_secret: '3429870605882e9af901eb4035842469',
         username     : '',
         password     : ''
    };
  
  var access_token = '';  
  var list = this;
  
    this.login = function () {
   var parameters = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: list.server_url+list.workspace+'/oauth2/token',
    data: this.credentials
     };
   $http(parameters).success(function(data){
    if (data.error) {
     alert(data.error_description);
    }else {
     parameters = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: list.server_url+'api/1.0/'+list.workspace+'/cases',
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer '+data.access_token}
       };
    $http(parameters).success(function(data){
     location.href="http://localhost/sysworkflow/en/neoclassic/cases/main";
      list.cases = data;
    });
     
   }
   });
  };
    
  }]);
  
})();
```

My index.php is as below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="caseLister">
  <head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://www.processmaker.com/favicon.ico" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="listController as list">
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1>ProcessMaker Case Lister</h1>
        <h6>Build your own user interface using the new ProcessMaker REST API</h6>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="well well-sm col-xs-4 pull-right">
          <h4>PM Server details</h4>
          <strong>URL:</strong> {{list.server_url}}<br>
          <strong>Workspace:</strong> {{list.workspace}}<br>
          <strong>Client ID:</strong> {{list.credentials.client_id}}<br>
          <strong>Client Secret:</strong> {{list.credentials.client_secret}}
        </div>
        <form>
         <div class="input-group col-xs-6">
           <div class="input-group-addon">Username:</div>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="list.credentials.username">
         </div><br>
         <div class="input-group col-xs-6">
           <div class="input-group-addon">Password:</div>
           <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="list.credentials.password">
         </div><br> 
         <input class="btn btn-info" type="button" value="Get Case List" ng-click="list.login()"><br>
        </form>
        <div ng-show="list.cases.length > 0">
          <h3>CASE LIST ({{list.cases.length}})</h3>
          <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
      <thead><tr class="bg-primary">
       <th>#</th>
       <th>Case Number</th>
       <th>Process</th>
       <th>Task</th>
       <th>Sent By</th>
       <th>Due Date</th>
       <th>Status</th></tr></thead>
      <tr ng-repeat="case in list.cases">
       <td>{{$index + 1}}</td>
       <td>{{case.app_number}}</td>
       <td>{{case.app_pro_title}}</td>
       <td>{{case.app_tas_title}}</td>
       <td>{{case.app_del_previous_user}}</td>
       <td>{{case.del_task_due_date}}</td>
       <td>{{case.app_status}}</td></tr>
    </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `I am redirecting to the page i want` - where is this redirection taking place in the code you posted?

Comment: In app.js at the end location.href

Comment: yes, sorry, was looking and missed it :p